# how to create the replica from a specific version?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, replication

I have a default version SDE and I want to make a QC versioning in 2 levels then to create a checkout/checkin Replica from the child version is that possible ?

---

[image: thats how i want to make the tree]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be possible. When you create your replica use a geodatabase connection that looks at the version you want to be the parent. From the [help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/replica-creation-and-versioning.htm):

> The default version or any named version can be used as the replica version for the parent or child replica. Several replicas can also share the same replica version. See Creating a replica to see how to set the replica version on either the parent or child.